# Does GDAL rasterize used with polygons use the centre or top left of pixel?

Tags: gdal, rasterization, gdal-rasterize

I have found conflicting information on whether GDAL rasterize in practice uses the centre or top left of pixel when converting a set of polygons to a raster. Some posts have documented that the top left corner of the generated pixel is used for the burn value.

The source code of GDAL is here: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/alg/llrasterize.cpp#L57-L61
And it seems the 0.5s added throughout move the sampling for the burn value to the centre of the new pixel.

Does anyone have experience or knowledge of this?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to read the code but finally I decided to make a test and see what happens. First I digitized 4x4 points by using a distance of one unit between the points. Then I stored distinct attribute values 1-16 for the points. Finally I rasterized the points.

```
gdal_rasterize -tr 1 1 -ot byte -a burnvalue rasterizetest.jml rasterizetest.tif
```

This is how the source points and the rasterized image look in QGIS.

[image]

Then I added a new point at a corner of one pixel and the result is this:

[image]

Obviously the top-left corner is included in the pixel. The point with value 20 is the last point in my dataset and therefore it is rendered over the value 6 in the same pixel.

Placing a new point at a boundary burns the value to the pixel on the right hand side.

Your data are probably more complicated so I suggest showing the vectors and  rasterized image together with QGIS. Maybe that reveals how GDAL behaves. That way it is also possible to study the effect of the "all touched" switch https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html#cmdoption-gdal_rasterize-at

> Enables the ALL_TOUCHED rasterization option so that all pixels
> touched by lines or polygons will be updated, not just those on the
> line render path, or whose center point is within the polygon.
> Defaults to disabled for normal rendering rules.

Answer (score 0):

In the backend of 'glad_rasterize', the default pixel behavior is always to use the center of the pixel. Perhaps you were looking at the 'rasterie' Python Library? As far as I know there are not parameters in gdal which allow you to specifically change the burn and initial value without tweaking the back-end code.